# update query php postgres failing for no reason

Tags: php, postgresql, postgresql-8.4

I have this piece of code in PHP and using a PostgreSQL as the database. I am getting all the parameters from the GET. Have checked them by printing it. The formed query executes on a Postgres terminal but fails from the PHP script.

Here is the piece of code.

```
<?php

$link = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=postgres user=postgres password=password") or die('connection failed');

# Building the query
$newq=sprintf("update purchase_info set ....... comments=%s where id=%s",......,$comm,$id);

    print $newq; // This query runs on the postgres terminal
    $query=addslashes($newq); // to escape "" as one of my fields is comments
    $result=pg_query($link,$newq);

    if (!$result) {
        echo "An error occured.\n";
    }
    pg_close($link);
?>
```

Other queries run in the same script. This SQL statement has about 14 field being updated.

What Is going wrong hear.
Appreciate the help!

Comment: Nothing fails "for no reason".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `addslashes` to quote strings for PostgreSQL, you should use [`pg_escape_literal`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-escape-literal.php):

> **pg_escape_literal()** escapes a literal for querying the PostgreSQL database. It returns an escaped literal in the PostgreSQL format. **pg_escape_literal()** adds quotes before and after data. Use of this function is recommended instead of `pg_escape_string()`.

You should never use [`addslashes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) for quoting strings for a database:

> It's highly recommended to use DBMS specific escape function (e.g. `mysqli_real_escape_string()` for MySQL or `pg_escape_string()` for PostgreSQL)

You should be doing this:

```
$newq = sprintf("update purchase_info set ... comments=%s where id=%d", ..., pg_escape_literal($comm), $id);
```

I'm assuming that `id` is actually a number as well.

Comment: @HiteshDharmadasani: I'd also recommend that you look into prepared statements, placeholders, and PDO so that you don't have to muck about with quoting things yourself.

Comment: pg_escape_literal() is not yet available in any released version of php (5.4.0 being the latest currently). That's going to be a problem for most people!

Comment: @DanielVérité: Thanks, PHP isn't my usual environment.

Comment: @HiteshDharmadasani: Feel free to switch the accept to Daniel Vérité's if your PHP doesn't have `pg_escape_literal`.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you really want to inject parameters into the SQL query, the correct code would be:

```
$newq=sprintf("update purchase_info set ... comments='%s' where id='%s'",
   pg_escape_string($comm), pg_escape_string($id));
// DO NOT USE to addslashes, it is not correct
$result=pg_query($link, $newq);
```

Notice the single quotes surrounding the %s in the format string.
Also if id is an integer, it's better do use %d (no quotes) instead of '%s'

Comment: All the security apart.
will building my sql query like this
$newq="update purchase_info set  ... comments='".$comm."' where id='".$id."'";

 work too?

Comment: You almost certainly shouldn't be quoting the `id`, PostgreSQL wants numbers to be numbers.

Comment: Actually, PostgreSQL treats a literals in single quotes as being of type "unknown" until it is forced to resolve it.  In the absence of other information it will resolve to text, but you can generally use single-quoted literals in assignments of *any* type.  This is done so that custom data types, like global coordinates, can be treated as first-class objects with values assigned from literals without needing to explicitly cast the literals.

Comment: @kgrittn: Fair enough. I'd still call "quoting everything in sight" a bad cargo-cult habit from doing too much MySQL.

Comment: @kgrittn: While it certainly works to use a single-quoted literal for numbers it is generally **not** a good idea. If you have overloaded functions,  like `f(int)` and `f(text)`, PostgreSQL will assume the type `text` and pick the second function if you call `f('1')`, while it will pick the first (and fitting) one if you don't: `f(1)`.

Comment: @muistooshort: I refrained from comment on whether it was a good or bad thing to quote in this circumstance, because I don't know php well enough to know whether there might be value to quoting (with escapes) if this is otherwise unsanitized data.  I see lots of "bug" reports against PostgreSQL from people who don't understand that literals like that are of "unknown" type rather than character strings of some sort.  I thought it worth describing the behavior to help prevent such confusion.  Such understanding seems the antithesis of "cargo cult" mentality.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: Like I said, when forced to resolve a literal of "unknown" type in the absence of information indicating that it should do otherwise, PostgreSQL will resolve to text.  The function example is a good one.  I could provide some which generate an outright error which surprises people.  My aim is to eliminate that surprise, not encourage quoting of all literals.